# what is the different between "view" and "window" on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I use the Xcode and add a UI elements on that, but there have different XIB that I can choose from. there are application XIB, view XIB, and window XIB. I want the user tap, and go to the next screen. I don't know which UI element is suitable for my "next screen", I means, whether I choose the View XIB or a Window XIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an iPhone app, you create one UIWindow instance at the launch of the app (or the framework loads it from the XIB depending on how you've configured things). That UIWindow is never subclassed and it fills the whole screen.

The individual pages of user interface are UIView instances that are either instantiated in code or loaded from an XIB. These also are usually not subclassed - logic goes in UIViewController subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Window is the full screen size,  and can't be changed, while view is a view that can change sizes.